# how to activate modal window using bootstrap 3 when use select again?

Tags: jquery, html, select, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I tried this method below:

```js
$('select').change(function () {
  var addProj = $('select option:selected').val();
  if(addProj === 'addthis'){
    $('#myModal').modal();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select>
  <option>addthree</option>
  <option>addtwo</option>
  <option>addthis</option>
</select>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's works at the beginning, but later, when I select, after I click close on the modal window, then I select from the selected option and I click again, 
no modal window is shows.

How can I activate the modal window even when it is selected?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to initialize the `modal` first but not show it by passing the option [`show:false`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options).

When you want to show it (like the `select` value equal to `addthis` for example, you call the plugin method [`show`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modalshow).

The full story:

```js
var modal = $('#myModal').modal({
  show: false  
});

$('select').change(function () {
  var addProj = $('select option:selected').val();
  if(addProj === 'addthis'){
    modal.modal('show');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select>
  <option>addthree</option>
  <option>addtwo</option>
  <option>addthis</option>
</select>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry i didn't make myself clear but what i want to do is that ,after i select addthis this option ,modal window shows,then the selected option is add this right? but this time,browser will not know it ,it insists that the status is selected.so if you selected addthis again will not activate modal window.so it is more or less a bug,how to make browser know we want to select again after  add this remains selected?

Comment: OK. Then the answer of @Ijas Ahamed will do the job. If you don't want to to change the value of the `select` when the `modal` is show, you will need to use a plugin for this.

Comment: I will glad to hear how did you fixed this. Also, please accept **one of the answers** so it will be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your codes is onChange event handler is given to select options.

When you select first time to "addthis" onchange function is trigered. Next time when you select "addthis" this function is not called because value is not changed. When you select "addtwo" and then "addthis" model is opened.

If you want to open modal for your second click of "addthis" , you need to change select option value to "addtwo" or "addthree" on modal close.

Thy this code

```
$('#mySelect').change(function () {
  var addProj = $('select option:selected').val();
  if(addProj === 'addthis'){
    modal.modal('show');
  }
});

$('#my-modal').on('#myMdal', function () {
     $('#mySelect').val("addtwo");
});



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="mySelect">
  <option>addthree</option>
  <option>addtwo</option>
  <option>addthis</option>
</select>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```